# When to stop working on a PCB layout

Tags: pcb, design, eaglecad

I currently have this PCB layout for a project:

[image]

Now I'm unsure if I should invest more time to get rid of some vias or if I just should finish it off and order the board.

Do vias matter for such short traces? For comparsion: the ICs are TSSOPs and the passives are 0603s.

**Additional Info:**:

- No I don't know the maximum signal frequency yet. But it will be around 10-100kHz.
- ICs are MAX312L and 74LVC125AT

So it boils down to the question 'when should I stop working on a PCB'.

Comment: How much does an extra via cost you? Maybe a few pennies. How much is your time worth? More than that.

Comment: Is this done professionally? To simply say 'ok its done routed, lets order the pcb!'. What about design ethics?

Comment: A more important issue is, is your ground net fully connected, and is there any connection between ground and wherever power is coming from?

Comment: I'm going to duplicate the circuit and then connect all the power rails together. I just left it out for simplicity. I don't need vias for the power.

Comment: I agree with @ThePhoton . I wouldn't even worry about the vias. Right now I would just focus on shortening the traces. For example, if you move the topmost via downward, you can also move that long square-ish trace down to shorten it. I see several traces that could benefit from similar changes.

Comment: The passive in the upper right corner, pad 2 doesn't connect to anything. (If you included designators, it would be easier to discuss)

Comment: @ThePhoton oopss.. sorry, forgot about that

Comment: Insufficient documentation on the PCB (silkscreen) will make the people assembling/using it more prone to error.

Comment: ThePhoton made a good point. I'm seeing a lot of islands with dead copper (ex: the component on the top right is connected to a pour but that island is not connected to the rest of the bottom layer pour).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You usually don't pay for vias if the density is reasonable and the quantities are not astronomical.

Vias don't make much difference unless your edges are less than a nanosecond or two, for your frequencies forget about it.

You're done. Maybe you need a deadline.. .

P.S. Sometimes it's better to let the layout sit for a few days and then come back to the schematic and really look it, and then the layout. Modern EDA tools usually make sure the layout matches the schematic, but sometimes what you put in the schematic isn't what you thought you put there.